# How can I hard reset a USB device?

Tags: 10.04, usb, usb-drive

I have a USB device (a modem) that is really finicky.  Sometimes it works fine, but other times it refuses to connect.  The only solution I have found to fix it once it gets into a bad state is to physically unplug the device and plug it back in.  However, I don't always have physical access to the machine it is plugged in on, so I'm looking for a way to do this through the command line.

[This post](http://tuxtweaks.com/2010/01/restart-usb-in-ubuntu-jauntykarmic/) suggests running:

```
sudo modprobe -w -r usb_storage; sudo modprobe usb_storage
```

However I get an "unknown option -w" output.  This slightly modified command:

```
sudo modprobe -r usb_storage
```

Fails with the message FATAL: Module usb_storage is in use.  If I try to kill -9 the processes marked [usb-storage] before running they refuse to die (I think because they are deeply tied to the kernel).

Anyone know of a way to do this?

NOTE: I [cross-posted this on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/176319/hard-reset-usb-in-ubuntu-10-04) as I didn't know which was more appropriate.  I will delete and/or link whichever one is answered first.

Comment: This question seems abandoned, there is no visible activity or information added to it for several months. I have flagged a moderator and am voting for it to be closed. If you feel that the question is not abandoned and that you still suffer from this issue please flag a moderator so that it can be re-opened.

Answer (score -1):

Your modem driver might still be loaded.
check with "sudo lsmod" which modules are using  usb_storage or any other usb modules.
You have to "sudo modprobe -r the other modules" first.

Comment: The entry for usb_storage reads:
usb_storage            39425  1

Doesn't seem to indicate any dependencies?

Comment: the 1 means one module is using it. go through the lsmod list and check next to which module usb_storage appears.

Comment: f.e scsi_mod might use it:

scsi_mod              101301  6 usb_storage,firewire_sbp2,sg,sd_mod,sr_mod,libata

Answer (score -1):

Try to close any relevant service and afterwards try to remove  the dependencies first.

There is always the cruel way of **rmmod** but i don't suggest because it could crash your system

You could also make a script that **disable usb power** on such cases

Comment: How would I disable USB power?

Comment: Either by writing a udev rule or by modifying 
/sys/bus/usb/devices/USBNUM/power/level

With a little googling you can find it {i 'm sorry but i can't have a look at it this moment :<}